# T-SQL side-by-side coupling of data at the end

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following screenshot, I would like to merge the data in the YorumYapanAdsoyad column on a single line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvm2X.png)

[image]

It should be this way;

```
 8 | Fiat Linea 1.3 Multijet | Ahmet, Selami
12 | Vw Golf                 | Ertem, Selim
```

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT,Araclar varchar(100),YorumYapan varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 8 , 'Fiat Linea 1.3 Multijet' , 'Ahmet'  UNION ALL
SELECT 8 , 'Fiat Linea 1.3 Multijet' , 'Selami' UNION ALL
SELECT 12 , 'Vw Golf'                 , 'Ertem' UNION ALL
SELECT 12 , 'Vw Golf'                 , 'Selim'

SELECT DISTINCT  ID
                ,Araclar
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', '+YorumYapan 
                    FROM @Table i WHERE i.ID=o.ID FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS YorumYapan
FROM @Table o
```

Result

```
ID  Araclar                  YorumYapan
------------------------------------------
8   Fiat Linea 1.3 Multijet  Ahmet, Selami
12  Vw Golf                  Ertem, Selim
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,for earlier versions on SQL (2016 and down)

```
       ;WITH Tmp (UrunId, Araclar , YorumYapanSoyad) as
       (
       SELECT 8 , 'Fiat Line 1.3 Multijet' , 'Ahmet'
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT 8 , 'Fiat Line 1.3 Multijet' , 'Selami'
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT 12 , 'Vw Golf' , 'Ertem'
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT 12 , 'Vw Golf' , 'Selim'

       )


       SELECT UrunId ,  Araclar ,
        (SELECT STUFF(
                (SELECT ', ' + YorumYapanSoyad 
                FROM Tmp b
                WHERE B.Araclar = T.Araclar
                AND b.UrunId = t.UrunId 
                FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') 
        ) YorumYapanSoyad

       FROM Tmp t
       GROUP BY UrunId ,  Araclar
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the recipe I use. As I don't know your table names, I made this example using sys.tables and sys.columns. Basically, the function [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) is your friend here.

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    STUFF 
        (
            (
                SELECT ', ' + c.name
                FROM sys.columns c
                WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 
            1, /*string start*/
            2, /*string length*/
            '' /*replaceWith*/
        )
FROM sys.tables t
```